# Serialization issue with SortedSet, Arrays, an Serializable

Tags: java, list, serialization, set, sortedset

I have this before the process:

```
protected void onPostExecute(SortedSet<RatedMessage> result) {
    List<Object> list=Arrays.asList(result.toArray());
    lancon.putExtra("results", list.toArray()); // as serializable
}
```

then in the other part I have

```
Object o=this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("results");
//at this point the o holds the correct value (checked by debugger)
RatedMessage[] rm = (RatedMessage[]) o;// this line hangs out w ClassCastException
resultSet = new TreeSet<RatedMessage>(new Comp());
Collections.addAll(resultSet, rm);
```

Why I get the ClassCastException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it to work this way:

```
Serializable s = this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("results");
Object[] o = (Object[]) s;
if (o != null) {
    resultSet = new TreeSet<RatedMessage>(new Comp());
    for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        if (o[i] instanceof RatedMessage) {
            resultSet.add((RatedMessage) o[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I applied successfully this approach when all other failed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry; I overlooked the use of the no-arg `toArray()` call.

Please note that there's overloaded [`toArray(T[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])) method that takes an array as an argument.

By using this form, you can control the component type of the array, and it will work as expected.

```
protected void onPostExecute(SortedSet<RatedMessage> result) {
  lancon.putExtra("results", result.toArray(new RatedMessage[result.size()]));
}
```