# Save a custom ListView's instance state?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a custom `ListView` that uses a custom `ArrayAdapter` (which basically just overrides `getView()`). This custom adapter uses as its backend a `List<CustomObject>`. The elements in this `List` are retrieved from the network, so I would like to save it in `onSaveInstanceState()`. However, I can't find a way to put a `List<E>` in a `Bundle`. I'm thinking this is a common task, saving a custom array in the instance state. How do other people do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize a `List<E>`, you need to transform to an `Array` and use that when you pass a serialized object. Then read out the array and transform into a list. See this questions, it's about [sortedset serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136922/serialization-issue-with-sortedset-arrays-an-serializable) `E` also must be serializable.

Look into `.toArray` or `putStringArray` either `putStringArrayList`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it guided me to the right direction. I ended up casting my List to an ArrayList, which is serializable and works perfectly. You probably would've suggested the same thing if I had mentioned my `List<E>` is actually instantiated as an `ArrayList<E>`, but unfortunately I didn't.