# Send ArrayList<GeoPoint> array in putExtra method

Tags: android

I have created Intent and I put data using `putExtra`method.

Now I want to put my `geoPointsArray`type variable to my intent object, here is type of geoPointsArray :

```
List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
```

In existing methods `putExtra`I can't find how to put my custom type.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`GeoPoint` must be Parcelable or Serializable. So you should subclass it to add these functionalities as I think they miss from the original implementation.

Then look into these other questions they will help you.
[Serialization issue with SortedSet, Arrays, an Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136922/serialization-issue-with-sortedset-arrays-an-serializable)

Comment: Do you still need the code, as it is on the linked question. For parcelable just implement the `Parcelable`

Comment: @Pentium10  can you please give me code for implementing Parcelable for my type. THANKS!!

Comment: Just define your GeoPoint class as this:`public class MyGeoPoint implements Serializable`

Comment: I send mapIntent.putExtra("parc", new MyGeoPoint()); using sendBroadcast(mapIntent); to reciver. In onReceive I get extra using:Serializable prp;  prp =intent.getExtras().getSerializable("parc");. Can you please tell me how can I extract this information for use

Comment: MyGeoPoint class :         public class MyGeoPoint implements Serializable{
            
            int a = 1000;    
            
        }