# How to send ArrayList<object> from one activity to second activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to pass "ArrayList objArrayList" from one activity to second activity and want to receive there. I am creating a simple class  in that there are four arraylist. I m creating object of that class and calling method of that class by passing parameters to be added in arraylist. After that I m adding that class object in objArrayList.
  HOw can I pass objArrayList from one activity to second activity and receive it there?

Thanks,
Vishakha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

You have a few options:

1) Use the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) from the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

3) Use the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) shortcut method of the Intent

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

**New Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this getter is just for example purpose, can differ
if (myIntent !=null && myIntent.getExtras()!=null)
     String value = myIntent.getExtras().getString(key);
}
```

***NOTE:*** Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types, Parcelables, and Serializables. I just used Strings for demonstrational purposes.

Your Arraylist class must be Parcelable or Serializable. So you should subclass it to add these functionalities as I think they miss from the original implementation.

Then look into these other questions they will help you.
[Serialization issue with SortedSet, Arrays, an Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136922/serialization-issue-with-sortedset-arrays-an-serializable)

Comment: for option 2, I can't see any "extras" that can apply to mBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard Intent mechanism. Put your list to extras of intent and pass it.